# Most efficient way to check generate combinations with condition

Tags: python, combinatorics, cpython

In python, [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) offers the method of generating [combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) for a given list *n* and length *L*. I am looking for the most efficient / quickest way to generate all combinations, which fulfil the condition of not being a [superset](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) of a predefined list.

```
results = []
for combination in itertools.combinations(n, L):
   for item in subset_list:
       if set(combination).issuperset(set(item)):
          continue
       else:
          results.append(combination)
```

Yet, for large *n* this might become quite complicated. I am looking for the most efficient way to not generate all combinations in the first place and check upon their conditional success but consider the condition while generating the combinations.

Comment: what kind of entries are possible in the list?

Comment: hmm, naturally strings but lets make an assumption whatever is easier. Mapping strings to integer via dictionary shouldn't be an issue. :)